# Regex Ruby How to group every word within parentheses

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm trying to get all the words between the parentheses after a specific word and the end of the string.

For example, I have this case:

```
p " some other text in downcase LOREM (foo, bar)".scan(/ LOREM \((.*?)\)\z/m)
# [["foo, bar"]]
```

The regex is getting `foo, bar` which is between the parenthesis, it's okay, but I'd like to get them like two separate elements within a single array, meaning:

```
["foo", "bar"]
```

That's to say, the regex should group every words as a separate element.

My intention is to get everything between `LOREM (` and the last closing parenthesis `)`.

I've tried adding `(\b\w+\b)`, which groups every word in the string. But when adding it to the attempt to get the words from the parenthesis, it returns nothing.

Comment: I've done an edit. btw, were you informed by SO that I had done so? (I've always wondered but never asked.)

Comment: This is an interesting question, but in practice I think it would be much faster to code, and permit simpler and more thorough testing, to employ a method that does not rely on a regular expression exclusively. For example: if `str = "text LOREM (foo, \"bar\")"` then `str[/(?<=LOREM \()[^)]+(?=\))/].split(/,\s*/) #=> ["foo", "\"bar\""]`, where `str[/(?<=LOREM \()[^)]+(?=\))/] #=> "foo, \"bar\""`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
.scan(/(?:\G(?!\A)\s*,\s*|\sLOREM\s+\()\K\w+(?=[^()]*\)\z)/
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/b0ElU1) and the [Rubular regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/zqcknd8qou0c4w). You may replace `\w+` with `[[:alnum:]]+`, or `\p{L}+` (to only match letters), or `[^\s,()]+` (to match any 1+ chars other than whitespace, `,`, `(` and `)`), it all depends on what you want to match inside the paretheses.

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!\A)\s*,\s*|\sLOREM\s+\()` - either the end of the previous successful match and a `,` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces, or whitespace, `LOREM`, 1+ whitespaces and `(`
- `\K` - omit the text matched so far
- `\w+` - consume 1+ word chars
- `(?=[^()]*\)\z)` - immediately to the right, there must be 0 or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then `)` at the end of the string.

Comment: That's impressive. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having problems, I didn't know I could come up with the content between parens wrapped by quotes `description, \"name\"`, clearly this is now getting the elements with the quotes, which I'm trying to figure out how.

Comment: @sab `/(?:\G(?!\A)\s*,\s*"?|\sLOREM\s+\()\K\w+(?=[^()]*\))/`, see [demo](https://rubular.com/r/RQWqOltnENgi3y).

Comment: You used the test string `' some other text in downcase LOREM (foo, bar) MORE text LOREM (description, "name")'` against the regex in your comment above. It matched `'foo'`, `'bar'`, `'description'` and `'"name"'`, as desired. If, however, `'foo'` is changed to `'"foo"'`, `'"foo"'` and `'bar'` are no longer matched. Also, that regex, unlike that in your answer, does not end with the anchor `\z`. Is that anchor needed? That is, must the string end with the right parenthesis following the words to be extracted? "Coder on the verge of extinction." Nice!

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland. I don't think the received string can be of a form more than `LOREM (description, name)` or `LOREM (description, "name")`, which is already covered by Wiktor's comment. If isn't, then I'll create a new question. I really appreciate the time both has taken and so the answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
r = /
    (?<=       # begin a positive lookbehind
      LOREM[ ] # match 'LOREM '
      \(       # match left paren
      |        # or
      ,[ ]     # match a comma followed by a space
    )          # end positive lookbehind
    (?:        # begin a non-capture group
      [^, ")]+ # match one or more characters other than ',', ' ', '"' and ")"
      |        # or
      \"       # match a double quote
      [^, ")]+ # match one or more characters other than ',', ' ', '"' and ")"
      \"       # match a double quote
    )          # end non-capture group
    (?=        # begin a positive lookahead
      .*\)     # match any number of characters followed by a right paren
    )          # end positive lookahead
    /x         # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

Conventionally this is written

```
r = /(?<=LOREM \(|, )(?:[^, ")]+|\"[^, ")]+\")(?=.*\))/
```

Let's try it.

```
str = "some other text in downcase LOREM (foo, \"bar\", \"baz), daz"
```

```
str.scan(r)
  #=> ["foo", "\"bar\""]
```

The first match, `"foo"`, matches

```
str.scan /(?<=LOREM \()[^, ")]+/
  #=> ["foo"]
```

That is, this matches one or more characters other than a comma, space, double quote or left parenthesis, immediately preceded by `"LOREM "` followed by a left parenthesis.

The next attempted match begins at the end of `"foo"`. There is no match of `"L"` in `"LOREM"` so an attempt is made to match `", "`, which is met with success. `[^, ")]+` does not match `"bar"`, so an attempt is made to match `\"[^, ")]+\"`, which is successful. As `", "` is matched within the lookaround it is not part of the match returned. This matches `'"bar"'`.

`\"baz` is not matched because it has no closing double quote.